# In which version of chrome was the bug started that does not show perfectly formData/params/payload of requests inside devtools?

Tags: google-chrome

In which version of chrome was the bug started that does not show perfectly formData/params/payload of requests inside devtools?

This also happens when there is recaptcha-response

My version is 109.0.5414.74 (Official Version) 64 bits, OS Ubuntu  20.04 LTS

[image]

Comment: I'm really curious about what you'll do with that information. If you were a Chromium dev, able to fix that, I'd assume you'd already have heard of bisect-builds.py and would be able to get that info by yourself. So, I'll assume your goal is not to fix the issue, but then what is it? Sure we could run a bisect for you, but I doubt that will help anyone in the future and I even doubt it will help you at all. Maybe you're interested in something else than what your question currently asks for?

Comment: I'm not a Chromium dev, but with this information I could look for a version without bug, download the browser and use it.